# How to get notification when push notification is received in iOS without AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I'm building static library for iOS for push notifications. How can I find out when push notification is received without having access to `AppDelegate`? In other words, I don't want user to call some libraries delegate in order to tell to lib when push notiication is received. `AppDelegate` has this method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and it would be perfect if I could receive notification when that method is being called. I thought `NSNotificationCenter` must be solution, but there is no such notification that can be received through adding observer to `NSNotificaitonCenter` which will be fired when push notification is received. Or am I wrong?

However, there is one solution, not the cleanest one I must admit, where one can receive `AppDelegate` being set by user, save it to property and make new `AppDelegate` that will route everything to previously set `AppDelegate`. (on `dealloc`, property should be updated) But, that would mean that only one library can   do that, so I don't think that's the way to do it. Here's code for it:

```
{
    ....
    self.applicationDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return [self.applicationDelegate application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need subclass in your's library `UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>`, implement in it `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.
And make user of yours library to subclass yours appdelegate class.

Comment: I don't know whether this will work but I liked the idea and want to give it a try.